# trouble when running tansorflow project

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1

I was trying to run main.py of [this project](https://github.com/LucaAngioloni/ProteinSecondaryStructure-CNN) on my m1 macbook and got this output:

```
Collecting Dataset...


Time elapsed getting Dataset: 25.09 s
Using CullPDB Filtered dataset

Hyper Parameters

Learning Rate: 0.0009
Drop out: 0.38
Batch dim: 64
Number of epochs: 35

Loss: categorical_crossentropy

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   

...
...

2021-04-28 11:24:42.005679: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:136] Profiler session initializing.
2021-04-28 11:24:42.005933: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:155] Profiler session started.
2021-04-28 11:24:42.005978: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:172] Profiler session tear down.
2021-04-28 11:24:48.497673: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-04-28 11:24:48.502759: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:126] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
2021-04-28 11:24:48.516051: F tensorflow/core/grappler/costs/op_level_cost_estimator.cc:710] Check failed: 0 < gflops (0 vs. 0)type: "CPU"
model: "0"
num_cores: 8
environment {
  key: "cpu_instruction_set"
  value: "ARM NEON"
}
environment {
  key: "eigen"
  value: "3.3.90"
}
l1_cache_size: 16384
l2_cache_size: 524288
l3_cache_size: 524288
memory_size: 268435456
```

and got `error code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)`
I am running in miniconda virtual env with necessary dependencies installed.
Is there any solutions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to check the TensorFlow web site to see if they have a version that supports the M1 chip.  TensorFlow code is highly optimized for each individual CPU type.  It may not be there yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I did not use proper version of TensorFlow. I finally got an answer by following [this page](https://www.cyberlight.xyz/passage/tensorflow-apple-m1), which tells me to install apple version Tensorflow and use conda environment, it solves the problem.